# Ansible: TASK - is there an easy way to get Ansible to show the actual path of the source file on failure?

Tags: ansible

Oftentimes, when I'm running Ansible it will output:

```
TASK [relative/path/to/directory : name]
fatal: etc...
```

Now, when I've got a large repo that might be importing in other repos it takes some mental overhead to figure out where this directory is. And when you have to do this many times a day it gets annoying.

Is it possible to get Ansible to simply output the absolute path where the error happens?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your question: ansible doesn't typically show *any* path information in the `TASK [...]` header. It shows the name of the role (if the task is part of a role) and the value of the task `name`, if set, or the name of the running module.

Answer (score -1):

Turn on verbose logging:
`ansible-playbook <more arguments> -vvvv`
This will output a stack trace including the file and line number in case of an error.